# How to have two sliders?

Tags: java, swing, listener, layout-manager, jslider

How do I go about adding in another slider with an output? I want the slider just below the current one. So currently I have one slider working and just want to add another one. Do i need to add another panel or..?

```
public class Lab6Part3 extends JFrame implements ChangeListener {

JSlider slider = new JSlider();
JLabel outputLabel = new JLabel("Volume");

public Lab6Part3(){

    slider.setMaximum(30);
    slider.setMinimum(0);

    slider.addChangeListener(this);

    getContentPane().add(outputLabel);
    getContentPane().add(slider, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    setSize(300,200);
    setVisible(true);
}
public static void main (String[] args){
    new Lab6Part3();
}
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e){
    outputLabel.setText("Volume:  " + slider.getValue());
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have them both in the `NORTH` region, you will need to create a new `JPanel` to host them.  This is because you can only have one child in each region of a `BorderLayout`.

You can then add both of your `JSlider`s to this new `JPanel`.